# covariation of martingales

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

For a bivariate brownian motion $(B_t,W_t)_t$ we have that the covariation is given by $\langle W,B\rangle _t = t\rho$ where $\rho$ is the (constant) correlation between $W$ and $B$. Does this hold particularly because for fixed $t$, $(B_t,W_t)$ are multivariate normal? If not is there a counter example when $B_t$ and $W_t$ are brownian motions which are not mutually normal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

an extension of Lévy's theorem on the characterization of Brownian motion in the multivariate case is given in George Lowther 's blog [here theorem 2](http://almostsure.wordpress.com/2010/04/13/levys-characterization-of-brownian-motion/).

It asserts that if your process is a continuous local martingale with covariation of the type you state in your post then it has to be a multidimensional Brownian motion.

Now here is a "kind" of counterexample where only the marginals are Brownian motions. You specify the joint law by any non gaussian copula (depending on $t$) and the resulting process is not a bi-dimensional Brownian motion (and hence can't be a continuous local martingale otherwise it would contradict Lévy's characterization !!!)

Best regards

Comment: Can you give a concrete counterexample of what you have mentioned in the end?